# Selenium: selectWindow is not working outside of the testcase

Tags: selenium-ide

The test:

Testcase 1 has one selenese: openWindow | ${url} | ${name}

Testcase 2 has one selense: selectWindow | ${name} |

And it returns an error: [error] Could not find window with title ${name}.

If the two selenses are in one testcase, the test passes. 
I was looking in the docs: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.SelectWindow.html , but didn't find any related restrictions about the method - you can select windows only opened in the same testcase. Is that a known limitation or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should be able to pass variables around within the same test suite. That should allow you to use selectWindow within different tests:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=fa55fa6800d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a known limitation. There may be away around it but I am unaware of it(maybe you could try using a different tab for each test). Your best bet is to use the webdrivers. I have migrated from using the selenium firefox extension to C#, there is no comparison in the benefits of using this.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. I believe variables can be passed around among tests within the same test suite: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=fa55fa6800d4

So this should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

There is this open bug: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1136
which may be causing what you're seeing. Try selectWindow by another method (instead of the name, look by title)